# @wire method gives error 'Cannot read property 'keyword' of undefined' even though variable is declared

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a `@wire` function which calls an apex method which should return some list of contacts. However I get the following error on page load:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyword' of undefined
```

Here is my JS controller:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import findContacts from '@salesforce/apex/ContactComponentController.findContacts';

export default class ContactList extends LightningElement {
    contacts;
    error;
    keyword;

    @wire(findContacts, { accountId: '$recordId', keyword: this.keyword }) 
    wiredContacts({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.contacts = data; 
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.contacts = undefined;
        } 
    }
}
```

Here is my Apex method:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Contact> findContactsFull(String accountId, String keyword) {
    String queryString = '';
    String key = '%' + keyword + '%';

    queryString += 'SELECT Id, Name, Email, Birthdate, Title, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId=:accountId ';

    if(keyword != null) {
        queryString += 'AND Name Like :' + keyword;
    }

    return database.query(queryString);
}
```

As far as I can tell `keyword` is defined at the top of the JS so I don't understand why I would get an undefined error. Even if I give a string value to `keyword` I get the same error.

Comment: replace `this.keyword` to `'$keyword'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `this` while passing arguments to the wired methods.

Use `'$propertyName'` instead, just like you have done for accountId.

This should work.

```
@wire(findContacts, { accountId: '$recordId', keyword: '$keyword' }) 
wiredContacts({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.contacts = data; 
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
        this.contacts = undefined;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Knew it had to be something simple! Thanks